# Xcode Debug Memory Graph doesn't show object/edge name

Tags: ios, xcode9

Xcode 9 GM

When I opened the memory graph, it showed like this and made me confusion to see the graph.

If someone who knows how to show the text on the object/line please show me. Thanks!

[image: xcode]

Answer (score 7):

You should zoom into the graph using the trackpad like this

[image]